# Pass vector of symbols as function argument and convert to character vector

Tags: r, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

I have a function that I want to pass as an argument a vector of symbols and then internally I want to convert that vector to a character vector.

Minimal example:

```
fun <- function(symbols = c(a, b, c)) {
 # code to convert to character vector 
}

fun()
```

Output:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `rlang::quo_name`:

```
library(rlang)
fun <- function(symbols = c(a, b, c)) {
  symbols <- enquo(symbols)
  string <- quo_name(symbols)
  unlist(strsplit(gsub("(c\\(|\\)|\\s)","",string),","))
}

fun(c(apple, orange, pear))
#[1] "apple"  "orange" "pear"
```

I suspect you're actually trying to solve another problem with this, so it probably makes sense to post *that* as another question.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
fun <- function(symbols = c(a, b, c)) {
  # code to convert to character vector
  return(unlist(strsplit(
    gsub("c\\(|\\)|\\(|\\s+", "",
         deparse(substitute(symbols))), ","
  )))
}

fun()
```